# Statistically comparing two different cache hit algorithms

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, algorithms

I am comparing two different cache hit algorithms using four different training and testing sets. The training sets are related: 1 is a subset of 2 is a subset of 3 is a subset of 4. The same goes for the test sets. The result is two different matrices with cache hit ratios between 0 and 1, where higher values are better:

Algorithm A

```
                  test set 1:  test set 2:  test set 3:  test set 4:
training set 1:   0..1         0..1         0..1         0..1
training set 2:   0..1         0..1         0..1         0..1
training set 3:   0..1         0..1         0..1         0..1
training set 4:   0..1         0..1         0..1         0..1
```

Algorithm B:

```
                  test set 1:  test set 2:  test set 3:  test set 4:
training set 1:   0..1         0..1         0..1         0..1
training set 2:   0..1         0..1         0..1         0..1
training set 3:   0..1         0..1         0..1         0..1
training set 4:   0..1         0..1         0..1         0..1
```

I now want to determine the best algorithm. How can this be done? I have limited understanding of statistical concepts. I don't know the distribution of the data.

I thought about using a dependent sample t-test for each pair of cells in A and B, so that B is seen as the "treatment" and we then decide if the "treatment" was benefitial or not.

H0: There is no significant difference between the algorithms
H1: There is a significant difference between the algorithms

Is this method even remotely valid? Any help much appreciated!